# "Commands ignored until end of transaction block", with autocommit mode with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm writing a setup script for my Postgres database. As part of this, I want to create a user if it doesn't exist, and create the database if it doesn't exist, using the "POSTGRES" user and database to do this from. [According to the Psycopg docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control), I need to have autocommit *on*, in order for this to work, so I do that here.

```py
def postgres_create_user(username, conn, cur, password=None):
    """
    Create a postgres user, including a password if provided.
    """
    from psycopg2.sql import Identifier, Placeholder, SQL
    from psycopg2.errors import DuplicateObject, ProgrammingError

    # Run the CREATE USER
    try:
        if password:
            cur.execute(
                SQL("CREATE USER {} WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD {}").format(Identifier(username), Placeholder()),
                [password],
            )
        else:
            cur.execute(SQL("CREATE USER {}").format(Identifier(username)))

        print(f"User {username} created successfully")
    except DuplicateObject as e:
        # it's okay if user already exists
        print(f"User {username} already exists")


def postgres_create_database(conn, cur, database, user):
    """
    Create a Postgres database, with the given owner.
    """
    from psycopg2.sql import Identifier, SQL

    # create database
    cur.execute(SQL("CREATE DATABASE {} OWNER {}").format(Identifier(database), Identifier(user)))
    print("Database created successfully")

conn = default_engine.raw_connection()
conn.autocommit = True

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    print("Initializing the postgres user")
    postgres_create_user(
        config_url.username, conn=conn, cur=cur, password=config_url.password
    )   
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    print("Initializing the postgres database")
    postgres_create_database(
        conn=conn, cur=cur, database=config_url.database, user=config_url.username
    )
```

The trouble is that either of these functions (`postgres_create_user` and `postgres_create_database`) could fail. If the first fails (because the user already exists), and I try to run the second (CREATE DATABASE), I get this error:

```
megaqc_1  | psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

So it thinks I'm trying to use a failed transaction. But I enabled `autocommit` mode, so why is this happening? How can I successfully run both of these commands, ignoring failures?

Comment: I would tail the Postgres log and see what the server is receiving from the above code when the first command fails.

Comment: If I replace `default_engine.raw_connection()` with `psycopg2.connect('')` and add the needed imports, it works as expected for me.  Are you sure you are even using psycopg2?

Comment: Yes, the error message is from psycopg. Perhaps the connection I'm getting from SQLAlchemy is different from what it should be, somehow